# Controller getting input parameter slow, second onclick input is from first onclick input

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

For the context, in my first click, I get null for both input. And then in my second attempt onclick, the input result is from the first click. In my third attempt onclick, the input result is from the second click. I am wondering why is this happening ? seems like the data being sent slow ...I tried putting `await setData( data => ({...data, user_id: userId, user_name: userName}) )` but it didn't work.

How can I fix this ? The following are my code,

```
export default function SenaraiJualan({ app, auth, sales, action = 'create', sale }) {

    const { data, setData, post, put, errors, reset } = useForm({
        user_id: sale?.user_id ?? '',
        user_name: sale?.user_name ?? '',
    });

    const handleSubmit = async (e, userId, userName) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setData( data => ({...data, user_id: userId, user_name: userName}) )
        console.log('handleSubmit called')
        try {
            switch (action) {
                case "create":
                    await post(route("hantar.katalaluanpdf"))
                    Swal.fire({
                        text: "Kata laluan PDF telah berjaya dihantar",
                        icon: "success",
                    });
                    break;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                text: error,
                icon: "error",
            });
        }
    };

    return (
                  ...........

                <button onClick={ (e) => handleSubmit(e, sale.user_id, sale.user_name )} >
                               <RiLockPasswordLine
                                        className=" h-4 w-4"
                                        data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                                        data-tooltip-content="Hantar Kata Laluan"
                                />
                </button>
                 ...........
```

controller

```
public function hantarpassword(Request $request)
    {
        // Email
        // user_id
        $user_id = $request->user_id;
        $user_name = $request->user_name;

        dd($user_id, $user_name);
        $user_name_upper = strtoupper($user_name);

        // Generate password for PDF
        $userId = substr($user_id, -4);
        $user_name2 = substr($user_name_upper, 0, 5);
        $password = $userId . $user_name2;

        Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($user_name, $password) {
            $message->to('jabri@devwiz.my');
            $message->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'));
            $message->subject("Permintaan set kata laluan pdf baru... ");
            $message->html('<html> Tuan/Puan ' . $user_name . ', <html>
            <br> <html> Berikut adalah Kata Laluan anda untuk akses ke Dokumen RT: ' . $password . ' <br> <html>
            Jika anda tidak pernah membuat permintaan, email anda mungkin tersalah isi oleh orang lain. Anda boleh padam email ini dengan selamat.<html>');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Change `setData` to  `await setData({ ...data, user_id: userId, user_name: userName });`

Comment: event `click` fire right when it needs to be... look up on you code maybe something preventing this. This is jQuery and/or Javascript. There are no ways for Laravel or other stuff  preventing event propagnation

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I already tried that as I said in my post above but it didn't work

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco it did fire but the data isn't received simultaneously in this case. in my second click, the result from it is from the first click

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are working with react and attempting to set state value. If this is the case, state takes time to change the value; this is why this issue is occurring, and its value will not change within that function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).